# How can use friendly url with htdocs?

Tags: php, htdocs

I have a website with URLS variables, but i can change for friendly urls like:

https://www.kanarinolta.es/impresion-oficina?name=bizhub&model=C650i

to this:

https://www.kanarinolta.es/impresion-oficina/bizhub-C650i/

I tried with this in htdocs file:

```
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+).php /impresion-oficina?name=$1&model=$2 [NC]
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: how about 
`RewriteRule ^/impresion-oficina/.+-.+$ /impresion-oficina/index.php?name=$1&model=$2 [NC,L]`

the selector should be .+

Comment: I just to try but it doesnt work

Comment: Did you enable the rewrite engine with `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: @loa_in_ yes, i'm using .htdocs for delete index.php form url and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure **mod_rewrite** is enabled and **htaccess** files allowed in your Apache configuration.

```
RewriteRule ^impresion-oficina/([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ impresion-oficina?name=$1&model=$2 [NC]
```

Should work for :

```
www.kanarinolta.es/impresion-oficina?name=bizhub&model=C650i

to

www.kanarinolta.es/impresion-oficina/bizhub-C650i/
```

Comment: But is a Joomla website... does that influence?

Comment: No it doesn't matter, what kind of error do you get ? Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: I also suspect the mod rewerite doesn't work. Because it should work, either mine on comment or Amine one. Both should work.

Comment: @Amine KOUIS yes a have mod_rewrite enable because i use .htacces to remove the index.php and works fine.

Comment: For example in htacees this work:

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: are you sure removing index.php from path isn't something that's set anyway in httpd.conf or other config files?

Comment: @loa_in_ No, because before writing that I always showed index.php in url and I spoke to the web server administrator and he told me that Rewriteengine is enabled. Thank you

Comment: @AmineKOUIS i just resolve it. It's works but without tue last '/' so the url is:

www.kanarinolta.es/impresion-oficina/bizhub-C650i instead of www.kanarinolta.es/impresion-oficina/bizhub-C650i/

Thank you so much!